# PHP - How to check no extension downloadable URL

Tags: php, web, php-curl

```
        $url=download.piriform.com/ccsetup524.exe

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        // don't download content
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

        if(curl_exec($ch) !== FALSE)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
```

This works fine - it returns *true* (that means the link is downloadable).

But when the url has no extension like

```
$url=https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B5a6JxhqgyoIdGFVeXFKSGZsd0E
```

it is not working.
It always returns *false* (that means the link is not downloadable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`curl`'s certificates are probably out of date. It isn't working because the second link is `https`. For a quick fix add:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
```

For a proper fix you need to download an up to date certificate bundle and set your php config to use it. Here's a tutorial on it:

https://snippets.webaware.com.au/howto/stop-turning-off-curlopt_ssl_verifypeer-and-fix-your-php-config/

Comment: You're welcome. Mark my answer as correct if it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You are making some weird assumptions:

> This works fine - it returns true (that means the link is downloadable).
>
> It always returns false (that means the link is not downloadable).

As [docs](http://php.net/curl_error) explain the return value of `curl_exec()` is `false` on failure (any kind of failure) and you have [curl_error()](http://php.net/curl_error) to find out what's wrong. Don't need to guess!